# Grails 3 - assign controller's variable in interceptor

Tags: grails, interceptor, grails-controller

I'm upgrading by Grails 2.5.1 web-app to grails 3, but I'm stuck with this problem: in my controllers I was using `beforeInterceptor`s to pre-calculate a set of variables to be used in their action methods.

```
class MyController {

    def myVar

    def beforeInterceptor = {
        myVar = calculateMyVarFromParams(params)
    }

    def index() {
        /* myVar is already initialized */
    }
}
```

Now that with Grails 3 interceptors are more powerful and on separate files, how can I achieve the same result? To avoid using request-scope variables, I tried with the following code

```
class MyInterceptor {

    boolean before() {
        MyController.myVar = calculateMyVarFromParams(params)
        MyController.myVar != null  // also block execution if myVar is still null
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() { /* nothing */ }
}

class MyController {

    def myVar

    def index() {
        println('myVar: '+myVar)
    }
}
```

but I get

```
ERROR org.grails.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver - MissingPropertyException occurred when processing request: [GET] /my/index
No such property: myVar for class: com.usablenet.utest.MyController
Possible solutions: myVar. Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: myVar for class: com.usablenet.utest.MyController
Possible solutions: myVar
at com.usablenet.utest.MyInterceptor.before(MyInterceptor.groovy:15) ~[main/:na]
```

I assumed (wrongly, apparently) that this would be feasible. Is there a solution? Thanks in advance!

Note: in my case MyController is an abstract class extended by all other controllers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I was missing is to declare `myVar` as `static`, as simple as that!

**Update**
If for any reason you cannot define the variable as `static`, you can set it as attribute on `request` object in the interceptor, and read it from there in the controller

```
// Interceptor
request.setAttribute('myVar', calculateMyVarFromParams(params))

// Controller
request.getAttribute('myVar')
```